# Using power query to group alternate rows

Tags: powerquery

[image]

Starting with the table above, the headers and their respective values are in alternating rows. For example for Nike, the Serial for the boots is 123 and Part No. is ABC, and it is sold on 12 Apr 22 for $23.03 with 20 left in stock. What I am trying to achieve by using power query is the following table:  [image]

I have tried adding an index and divide-integer 2 as there are 2 rows (1 header, 1 value) for each item sold and grouping using the resultant index. Then unpivot all except the index. [image]

Then split the Attribute and Value columns using #(lf)
[image]

But I'm stuck here and running out of ideas. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"AlternateRows"=Table.AlternateRows(Source,0,1,1),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(AlternateRows, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn( #"Added Index", "Custom", each Text.Split([Column2],"#(lf)")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Text.Split([Column4],"#(lf)")),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.2", each 
    Table.AddColumn(
        Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(
            Table.AddIndexColumn(
                Table.FromColumns({[Custom],[Custom.1]})
            , "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
        , {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value")
    ,"Key", each Text.From([Index]) & Text.End([Attribute],1))
),
#"Expanded Custom.2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.2", {"Value", "Key"}, {"Value", "Key"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom.2",{"Column2", "Column4", "Custom", "Custom.1"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Key]), "Key", "Value"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"01", "Serial"}, {"02", "Date"}, {"11", "PartNo"}, {"12", "Price"}, {"22", "Item"}, {"32", "Stocks Left"}, {"Column1", "Currency"}, {"Column3", "Brand"}}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Index"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Date", type date}, {"Price", type number}, {"Stocks Left", type number}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

[image]